# CSS based 50% Transparent border without using transparent image

Tags: css, fancybox

I need to make the border of fancy box transparent after i have made some modifications to it. For some reason i cant make it work with transparent.

I have create a sample example which is somewhat & i want to make the borders of the inner DIV transparent. i tried few thing but did not work. I would appreciate a pure CSS solution without using any transparent images

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xh3Z/)

Is their a way we can add Opacity to border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use color as transparent like this for making it fully transparent

```
border:10px solid transparent;
```

[**My fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xh3Z/1/)

And if you want to add opacity, than this approach of your's is correct, it does make the border opaque

```
border-color:rgba(17,17,17,0.7);
```

You can use this too `border-color:rgba(244,244,244,0.4);` [My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xh3Z/2/)

Comment: @ Alien, `border-color:rgba(17,17,17,0.7);` is not working for some reason this is the reason i am looking for alternatives. I want 50% transparency

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Which browser are you using? it works for me, just see this fiddle of mine http://jsfiddle.net/3Xh3Z/2/

Comment: @ Alien, Strange same thing was not working for me now it is working on jsFiddle.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker it is because `17, 17, 17` is more on a darker scale than what I've used which is `244, 244, 244` which is on whiter scale :)